# Dependency Injection without full interface

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I have a WCF service with a large interface. The client solution has a class library that utilizes the service but only one method + one data contract. I don't want the service reference in that class library project, but instead only in the main project.

I added an interface to this class library that has only the items I need. I then expose a method that accepts a parameter 'client' of type object that I cast to this interface. Whenever I run it I get "unable to cast". I am thinking this is because the interface on the client is missing many methods.

I looked at a Ninject library for WCF https://github.com/cyanfish/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.Client, but it assumes you included the entire interface from the server solution. I don't want to do this because it has other unrelated dependencies and I want to keep this class library clean. I could also have the main project in the client handle the service calls and pass around the results to the class library but that sort of defeats the purpose of breaking it out.

Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the object implement two different interfaces, one more complex than the other, and just register the type you need on the IOC container, like this:

```
    public class ImplementationObject: IComplexObject, ISimpleObject
    {
        public ImplementationObject(){}

        public string HelloWorld(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello {0}!", name);
        }
    }

    public interface IComplexObject
    {
        string HelloWorld(string name);
    }

    public interface ISimpleObject
    {
        string HelloWorld(string name);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't consider that option, however if I have to modify the back-end, I may be better off breaking out this single method to a separate svc endpoint and making a smaller interface that way.